# How to list package dependents on Nix?

Tags: nixos, nix

I get this error:

```
Package ‘python2.7-Pillow-6.2.2’ in /nix/store/...-nixos-21.05.1590.63ee5cd99a2/nixos/pkgs/development/python-modules/pillow/6.nix:19 is marked as insecure, refusing to evaluate.
```

when running `home-manager switch`.

I didn't install this package directly.

How can I see what are dependent derivations of this package to remove them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are looking for

```
nix-store --query --referrers /nix/store/...(insert full path here)...
```

Cf. https://nixos.org/manual/nix/stable/#operation-query-1